# java + maven + Jenkins + Pipeline + parallel stages ===> GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, maven, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline, multi-module

Where in , I tried with simple commands **mvn -v**, No Issues.

While executing the tests only , Its giving error.

How can we fix this ?

```
stage('suites') {
        parallel {
            stage('1 test') {
              sh 'mvn clean test <Some Maven Multi Module Projects>'
            }
            stage('2 test') {
              sh 'mvn clean test <Some Maven Multi Module Projects>'
            }
        }
}

When the execution started , %CPU is going very high (~400%) and failed with error
ERROR] GC overhead limit exceeded -> [Help 1]
```

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, can you try to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? If not, try to provide the full stack trace, which tell us the cause of the error.